# Using xpath with 'contains' in php

Tags: xpath, php, domxpath

I have:

```
<div class="posts">
    <p class="post">info: abcd</p>
    ....
</div>
```

I am trying to use xpath to select the

containing "info: abcd"

I have:

```
$DNlist = $xpath->query("//div[@class='posts']/p[contains(., 'info:')]]");
```

This gives:

```
Severity: Warning
Message: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think I see an extra closing `]` on the end...

Comment: Yes, in my quick test with your HTML fragment, it works if you remove that extra `]` http://codepad.viper-7.com/pjK8WR

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about one extra incorrect bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be on square bracket (`]`) to much. Try:

```
"//div[@class='posts']/p[contains(., 'info:')]"
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Its working now.